# Why won't summoning entitys with custom heads work in 1.12

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This command isn't working in version 1.12:

`/summon minecraft:zombie ~ ~1 ~ {ArmorItems:[{},{},{}, id:"minecraft:skull",Damage:3,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Wither}}]}`

What's wrong with it?

Comment: What is the result? Is there an error message?

Comment: I think you need `Count:1`.

Comment: Then please accept my answer (the check mark).

Comment: Btw, you also replaced a `{` with a space. But since my solution worked for you, you probably didn't do that in the game.

Answer (score 1):

Most items in commands need to be set to a count of 1, otherwise they have the standard amount of 0.

This is the working command:

```
/summon minecraft:zombie ~ ~1 ~ {ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:"minecraft:skull",Count:1,Damage:3,tag:{SkullOwner:MHF_Wither}}]}
```